# What's this connector?

Tags: identification, connector

Could you help me identify this connector so I can find its counterpart?

[image: connectors CNL802 and CNM803 on a Samsung TV power board]

CNL802 and CNM803 on a Samsung TV power board

Comment: If it's 0.100" pitch any standard 0.100" crimp housing should do even if it doesn't latch.

Answer (score 0):

It's the PCB header for a 2-row, unlatched, wire-to-board.

If you tell us the exact pitch (https://www.google.com/search?q=connector+pitch) we may be able to identify it.

Or, help yourself to this connector identification utility: connector:http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=interior_rect_conn&u=wire_to_board_conn&o=discrete_2row_w2b_conn